# L'uistitì beve il whisky. Perché in un caso usiamo "lo" e nell'altro "il"?

Tags: articles, foreign-words

- L'uistitì è una scimmietta sudamericana.
- Il whisky è un superalcoolico.

Non mi vengono in mente altre parole che inizino con *ui-* (e chiarisco che la U ha in entrambi i casi un suono semiconsonantico). Come mai in un caso si usano gli articoli *lo*, *gli*, *uno* e nell'altro *il*, *i*, *un*? e soprattutto come mai all'orecchio degli italofoni suona giusta e direi naturale questa distinzione?

**EDIT**: Una risposta qua sotto mi ha ricordato un altro prestito che inizia "foneticamente" per *ui-* ed è pure molto più usato della scimmietta e del superalcoolico citati: *il week-end*.

Comment: A me piace il tuo esempio perché l'ho letto in rima :)

Comment: "la pratica si è messa a camminare per conto suo". D'accordo. Ma penso che sarebbe bene ricordare che - mentre in tedesco si tratta di una doppia v - in inglese si tratta di una doppia u. Quindi, se vogliamo, abbiamo una ragione in più - oltre alla grammatica - per fare lo sforzo di dire l'whisky e l'weekend.

Comment: Che cosa intendi per “doppia u”?

Comment: Sono sicuro che se un tuo amico ti dicesse, 'mi passi l'whisky o lo whisky' tu penseresti 'ma come parla questo?' :)

Comment: non mi risulta che la W sia considerata una vocale nella lingua inglese. tra quelle che in italiano consideriamo "lettere straniere" soltanto la Y è talvolta considerata una vocale.. Dopotutto  prova a dire l'wi-fi senza incastrarti la lingua!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Treccani qui offre un'ottima [spiegazione](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/whisky-il-o-lo_(La_grammatica_italiana)/)

> in base alle regole di selezione dell’articolo determinativo, la forma corretta davanti alla parola straniera whisky dovrebbe essere l’, con l'elisione, come per tutte le parole che iniziano con il suono u (come per l’uomo)
>
> Tuttavia, nell’uso comune prevale la forma con l’articolo il, probabilmente per via del fatto che la w è percepita come consonante a pieno titolo

Comment: Stiamo quindi supponendo che nel linguaggio _parlato_ abbia influenza il fatto che graficamente si usa la W che "assomiglia" a una V (è una vu doppia, in effetti...)? Sarebbe interessante vedere se gli analfabeti sono più spinti a dire _l'whisky_ rispetto a chi sa come la parola sia scritta.

Comment: esattamente! La w è ufficialmente una "lettera straniera" (cioè nè vocale nè consonante), ma nell'uso comune è riconosciuta come consonante. (secondo Treccani)

Comment: Credo che il suono /w/ sia addirittura considerato una consonante fonologicamente e che sia solo il fatto che in italiano usiamo la stessa lettera per /w/ e /u/ (e.g. uovo, uomo...) che lo fa considerare una vocale

Comment: @MauroVanetti: A parte che ormai gli analfabeti veri e propri non sono poi tantissimi, ma purché siano una minoranza, quelli che lo sono sentiranno sempre dire “il whisky” e così lo useranno anche loro.

Comment: @DenisNardin Be', non è arbitrario che usiamo la stessa lettera, la U vocalica e la U semiconsonantica sono due suoni molto simili così come le due I. Non è un caso che in molte lingue si usi lo stesso segno grafico per indicarle o dei segni simili, anche in lingue che non usano l'alfabeto latino come per esempio il coreano. Anche altre vocali possono essere semiconsonantizzate (i veneti lo fanno con la E, i messicani con la O).

Comment: @MauroVanetti In ogni caso si tratta di una consonante vera e propria e non di una vocale per cui l'anomalia è semmai l'uso regolare di *lo* invece di *il*.. Ma se le lingue fossero completamente logiche dove sarebbe il divertimento?

Comment: @DenisNardin Si tratta di un fenomeno di confine tra le consonanti vere e proprie e le vocali: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonante_approssimante Come tutte le tassonomie è questione di convenzioni, ma il punto sostanziale è che esiste un continuum tra vocali e consonanti e quella roba lì sta a metà strada.